# Mouse click only after keyboard press sequence complete (pygame)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I want the code tied to a mouse click (`pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP`) to execute only AFTER the code tied to a spacebar press (`pygame.KEYDOWN` and `pygame.K_SPACE`) is 100% finished. Any mouse clicks prior to that should be ignored.

I know the second `if` statement won't work because of its relation, or lack thereof, to `for event in pygame.event.get():`. I just don't know how to write that correctly...

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

def task():

taskExit = False

while not taskExit:

     for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                print "Drawing..."
                screen.fill(gray)  
                    #<<<code to create pretty pictures>>>

                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    print "mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos  # where they clicked.
                        #<<<more code to interact with said pretty pictures>>>

task()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Maybe set a flag if the first condition is ```True``` then add the flag to the mouseup conditional and move it into the for loop suite (un-indent it).

Comment: @wwii Any other ideas? ahha. I have already tried that, sadly. The problem is less whether the person presses the space bar, and more ignoring the mouse until the code tied to the space bar press is 100% complete.

Comment: @wwii You can imagine the task as: "click a blue or green circle -- whichever is you favourite colour". The spacebar triggers those circles to be drawn. If the person clicks before the circles are drawn, it's simply an irrelevant response (e.g., their finger slipped in anticipation).

Comment: Sounds asycnchronous to me...  Can the user create a mouseup event and have it added to the queue while the circles are being drawn?  Maybe write a function that draws the stuff and when it is done, pushes a ```done``` event onto the queue.  Then while you are checking the queue, use a flag to signal that it is done? or maybe in the function add another loop to check the queue for mouseups before returning.

Comment: @wwii I can try something along those lines. Thanks for the help.

Comment: After reading a bit, i don't use pygame, if you update the screen once every *main* loop (```while not taskExit:```) after handling events, then any drawing you did as a result of *space-key* will be complete at the *top* of the next iteration. Maybe a combination of a flag and ```pygame.event.set_blocked```.  Or a specific event handler that includes a screen update and event checking and doesn't return till the user clicks something interesting.  Shirley this problem isn't unique, and has been solved - some dedicated searching methinks. I keep thinking coroutines.

Answer (score 2):

With a little **re-organisation** this will work as you expect. Export the code you want to execute after these events into two functions:

```
    def space_bar():
            print "Drawing..."
            screen.fill(gray)  
                #<<<code to create pretty pictures>>>

    def mouse_event():
            print "mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos  # where they clicked.
                #<<<more code to interact with said pretty pictures>>>
```

which allows you to call them both after the mouse event and give you control about the sequence the code is executed.

```
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        space_bar()

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        space_bar()
        mouse_event()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I wanted to do in this situation. In general however, your approach is one I should adhere to in the future as it is much tidier. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

So, for posterity, there is a very simple way to do this in pygame (oh, the value in actually reading the documentation...)

Namely, with `pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)` and `pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)` enables one to simply block the left mouse click at will. Very handy.

e.g.,

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))

def task():

    space_bar_pressed = 0

    taskExit = False

    while not taskExit:

         for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)  #blocking
                    print "Drawing..."
                    screen.fill(gray)
                    #<<<code to create pretty pictures>>>
                    pygame.display.update()
                    pygame.event.set_allowed(pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP)  #allowing
                    space_bar_pressed = 1

                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and space_bar_pressed == 1:
                    print "mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos  # where they clicked.
                    #<<<more code to interact with said pretty pictures>>>
                    pygame.display.update()

task()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: How will the program know that the drawing task is complete and mouse-ups can be enabled?

Comment: You're right; it doesn't "know" the task is complete. However, what my solution does is instruct the first `elif` (spacebar event) to block the second `elif` (mouse event) from starting until the first `elif` is done its job.

Comment: It seems typical that the screen update happens after the *event loop* handling, in the main game loop. So the figures won't be drawn on the screen till the next frame rolls around.  ```pygame.event.set_allowed``` would need to be positioned after (in time/sequence) the next ```pygame.display.update``` (or ```flip```).

Comment: @wwii That's correct. In the actual code I'm working on that's exactly what I do. I should make note of it in my 'answer' however. Thanks.